# How can you mirror the raspberry display?

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using my pi as a bitcoin miner and to start the mining program I use putty. However when I close putty it also stops my miner. What I'm wanting to do is start the mining program from the pi itself and then use putty as an external display so I can view the status of my miner.

Comment: A program called `screen` is your friend. It detaches running programs from the shell. (And the question should really be renamed as it is misleading right now).

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to solve this is the use of GNU `screen`, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). It allows you to multiplex multiple virtual consoles and therefore to access several different separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window or via a remote terminal session (e.g. ssh + putty).

Just start a (named) screen session with `screen -S mysession`, do what you want to do inside that session and detach it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>. Resume that session to pick up where you left with `screen -R mysession`.

Another tool to achieve this is `tmux` which is also quite powerful and can be heavily customized to your needs.

Comment: +1 I would also suggest tmux, which is similar to screen, but better in my opinion.

Comment: You're definitely right! I thought about it... but as usual forgot its name ;) And also - as usual - I will now think about changing to `tmux` ;) Thanks for the hint, added to the answer.

Comment: This is the only way I do bitcoin mining on *nix - Oh.. and everything else too after I log out from putty :D  Why is tmux better?

Comment: @ppumkin it is somewhat simpler to configure, a little easier to use (though if one just uses the simple functions of `screen` like detach and reattach it does not matter that much), and I think setting up multiple screens/"tabs" is somewhat simpler, but as always it is somewhat subjective. See also: https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/143463394889/tmux-102-getting-to-know-tmux

Comment: Ahh ok. Yea I am just a simple screen user of `screen -ls` and `screen -r pid`  :) I am sure that is just the bare minimum of that usability. Another nice thing of screen that I have used it as a serial terminal which was interesting new thing for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Also, have a look at the `nohup` command.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
tmux
```

to open a new virtual terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from the virtual terminal. To reconnect use:

```
tmux attach
```